# Automatically launching a pre-set configuration in VisualVM

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile functions in my java application using VisualVM (eclipse plug-in). Right now when I run an application, eclipse opens VisualVM and takes me to the profilers tab where I can start profiling by pressing the CPU or Memory buttons. Unfortunately, in the time that I take to manually do this, I lose significant number to iterations in my application to get a precise result.

I know I can set the default profiler setting for an application under Tools->Options->Profiling. But is there an option in VisualVM  where it can automatically fire the profiler on seeing a particular main function/application being launched.

Comment: whoa! either no one knows or no one wants to tell :P

Comment: This is something that's built into NetBeans by default. With this you won't miss any samples: https://profiler.netbeans.org/
I think it's the very same profiler that's in VisualVM.